# python: how to save dynamically rendered html web page code

Tags: javascript, python, d3.js, pyqt4

I have a setup where a web page in a local server (localhost:8080) is changed dynamically by sending sockets that load some scripts (d3 code mainly). 
In chrome I can inspect the "rendered html status" of the page, i.e., the resulting html code of the d3/javascript loaded codes. Now, I need to save that "full html snapshot" of the rendered web-page to be able to see it later, in a "static" way. 
I have tried many solutions in python, which work well to load a web and save its "on-load" d3/javascript processed content, but DO NOT get info about the code generated "after" the load. 
I could also use javascript to make this if no python solution is found.

Remember that I need to retrieve the full html rendered code that has been "dynamically" modified in time, in a chosen moment of time.

Here are a list of questions found in stackoverflow that are related but do not answer this question. 
Not answered: 
[How to save dynamically changed HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7554488/how-to-save-dynamically-changed-html)
Answered but not for dynamically changed html:
[Using PyQt4 to return Javascript generated HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25463279/using-pyqt4-to-return-javascript-generated-html)
Not Answered: 
[How to save dynamically added data to update the page (using jQuery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187601/how-to-save-dynamically-added-data-to-update-the-page-using-jquery)
Not dynamic: 
[Python to Save Web Pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502119/python-to-save-web-pages)

Comment: Have you tried selenium? http://docs.seleniumhq.org/

Comment: Not tried yet, and seems a possible solution, but outside the scope of my intentions for the question. If I do not find another solution, I will go that direction. Thanks.

Comment: solved using @Juca' s suggestion (selenium) see answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question could be solved using selenium-python (thanks to @Juca suggestion to use selenium). 
Once installed (`pip install selenium`) this code makes the trick:

```
from selenium import webdriver
# initiate the browser. It will open the url, 
# and we can access all its content, and make actions on it. 
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
url = 'http://localhost:8080/test.html'
# the page test.html is changing constantly its content by receiving sockets, etc. 
#So we need to save its "status" when we decide for further retrieval)
browser.get(url)
# wait until we want to save the content (this could be a buttonUI action, etc.):
raw_input("Press to print web page")  
# save the html rendered content in that moment: 
html_source = browser.page_source
# display to check: 
print html_source
```